# JAVA - user input java.util.NoSuchElementException from scanner

Tags: java

Causes exception when more than one scanner gets opened than closed. but works fine once close statements are removed.

```
reader.close();
```

Why do close statements work like that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IO {
    public static void choices() {
        boolean valid = true;
        do{
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?\n"
                    + " press '1' for event 
                                        creation.\n"
                    + " press '2' to display all 
                                        events.\n"
                    + " press '3' to exit prgram.");
            switch(inputInt()) {
                case 1: newEvent(); break;
                case 2: break;
                case 3: System.out.println("Goodbye"); valid = false; break;
                default: System.out.println("Invalid entery try again."); break;
            }
        }while(valid);
    }

    public static int inputInt() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = reader.nextInt();
        reader.close();
        return input;
    }

    public static String inputString() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = reader.next();
        reader.close();
        return input;
    }

    public static void newEvent() {
        System.out.println("What is the event name?");
        String name = inputString();
        Event e1 = new Event(name);
        Event.eventCreation(e1);
    }
}
```

throws this when case 1 is used

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input is exhausted,it will throw java.util.NoSuchElementException on method 'nextInt'.
When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.So when you invoke'reader.close()',it also close system.in inputstream.

System.in is a static propertie.So after closing, it is not available.

```
public final class System {

    /* register the natives via the static initializer.
     *
     * VM will invoke the initializeSystemClass method to complete
     * the initialization for this class separated from clinit.
     * Note that to use properties set by the VM, see the constraints
     * described in the initializeSystemClass method.
     */
    private static native void registerNatives();
    static {
        registerNatives();
    }

    /** Don't let anyone instantiate this class */
    private System() {
    }

    /**
     * The "standard" input stream. This stream is already
     * open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream
     * corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by
     * the host environment or user.
     */
    public final static InputStream in = null;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close--) clearly states:

> ```
> public void close()
> ```
>
> Closes this scanner.
>
> If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked.

You are closing `System.in` as well.

When asking questions here it is important to have reviewed all applicable documentation, which in this case means reading the Javadoc.

Comment: So system.in is being closed because it is an underlying method. Is there a way to close the scanner but not close system.in?

Comment: No need to close the scanner, but you should have only one `Scanner` on `System.in`, pass it in as a parameter.